# how to Use if in FlatList

Tags: react-native

*I have array which has images. I want to give show images in flatlist everything is ok now. But I want to show  some of  them I mean if condition is true show that image.*

**this is my code:**

```
 renderItem={ ({ item }) => 
 {
    if (true) {
            <View style={{ width: '22%', marginLeft: '3%', marginTop: '2%', alignItems: 'center' }} >

              <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('DescriptionPage', { data: item.call })}>
                <ImageBackground source={item.img} style={{ width: 60, height: 60 }} />
              </TouchableOpacity>

            </View>
          }
          else {
                ...
              }

        }
}
```

*if I  use like this  there is no error and it shows all images.*

```
<FlatList 
    data={images}
    keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
    numColumns={4}
    renderItem={ ({ item }) => 

    <View style={{ width: '22%', marginLeft: '3%', marginTop: '2%', alignItems: 'center' }} >

      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('DescriptionPage', { data: item.call })}>
        <ImageBackground source={item.img} style={{ width: 60, height: 60 }} />
      </TouchableOpacity>

    </View>


}
   />
```

**There is mistake here I dont know why :**

{
if (true)
 {
 ...
 }
else
 {
...
 }
}

Comment: `{ if (true) { return <View ... } else { return <View ... } }` . The first code didn't return JSX Element. The second code return a JSX Element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you forgot to add return inside if else condition:

do it like this:

```
renderItem={ ({ item }) => 
{
   if (true) {
     // add return
     return(
      <View style={{ width: '22%', marginLeft: '3%', marginTop: '2%', alignItems: 'center' }} >

      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('DescriptionPage', { data: item.call })}>
        <ImageBackground source={item.img} style={{ width: 60, height: 60 }} />
      </TouchableOpacity>

    </View>
     )

         }
         else {
           // add return
              return(
                ...
              )
             }

       }
}
```

Comment: Oh thx so much. I want to ask why I should add return. Why it doesnt show the view  if I dont put return  @Mervzs

Comment: think of it as normal render lifecycle method,. it requires to return a component so that it can render something.

Answer (score 0):

Just use this kind of setup:

```
return (isTrue) ? 
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('DescriptionPage', { data: item.call })}>
   <ImageBackground source={item.img} style={{ width: 60, height: 60 }} />
</TouchableOpacity> : null;
```

This should render the component if it is true, else, it won't render anything.